# View slide only first time app install

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic 1.
 I want to show ionic slide only first time of app install. So how can I know the app is run the first time or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such slides showing at first time save a key in local storage for the first time and every time the app starts check if that value exists in local storage if it exists it is not the first time your app is running and you have to do nothing in this case but if the value is not found in local storage it means that your app is running for the first time and show the slides and set the local storage key.

When your app runs:

```
if(localStorageService.get('showSlide') == undefined) {
   localStorageService.set('showSlide', false);
    //show slide logic should run
} else {
  // this block is running that means your localStorageService has already been set to false i.e it is not the first time your app is running.
//show slide logic should not run here do something else if you want.
}
```

Comment: also remember that if the user clears app data from settings then local storage will be cleared and on the next run your app will again show slides again for one time. but it is normal behaviour every app does that. clearing data is pretty much like reinstalling app.